# How to update a progress bar's value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

So what I'm trying to do is visually lower the health bar using a progress bar depending on certain conditions.

```js
const bgURLs = {
    "Air": "https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif",
    "Fire": "https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif",
    "Water": "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/947328402825377319/20625B881E545FF98AF1A48BAC52D4CBD207101B/",
  };


let options = document.getElementById("Options")
let computerChoice = getComputerChoice()
let playerChoice = ''   


let updatePlayerChoice = Options.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  playerChoice = e.target.id;    
  return playerChoice
})


function getComputerChoice() {
  const keys = Object.keys(bgURLs);    
  const randomIndex = [Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]   
  const compChoice = keys[randomIndex] 
  return compChoice 
}

// image shows up after clicked function
Options.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
  let tgt = e.target; 
  let player = document.getElementById("Player")
  let computer = document.getElementById("Computer")
  if (tgt.classList.contains("element")) {   
    player.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgURLs[tgt.id] + ')';   
    computer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgURLs[computerChoice] + ')';
  }
})
 

let playerHealth = document.getElementById("player-health").getAttribute("value")
let computerHealth = document.getElementById("computer-health").getAttribute("value");


function compareChoices() {
  if (playerChoice === "Fire" & computerChoice === "Water") {
     playerHealth -= 25
  } else if (playerChoice === "Fire" & computerChoice === "Air") {
     playerHealth -= 25
  } else if (playerChoice === "Fire" & computerChoice === "Fire") {
     playerHealth -= 25
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
      <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
      <h2>Elements Edition</h2>
        <h3>Choose Your Element</h3>
      <div id="Options" >
        <div id="PlayerBar">
            <p>Player Health</p>
            <progress id="player-health" value="100" max="100">
               </progress>
        </div>
        <div id="Air" class="element" >
            <p>Air</p>
        </div>
         <div id="Fire" class="element" >
             <p>Fire</p>
         </div>
         <div id="Water" class="element" >
             <p>Water</p>
         </div>
       <div id="ComputerBar">
            <p>Computer Health</p>
          <progress id="computer-health" value="100" max="100">
                </progress>
        </div>
         
      </div>

      <div id="Play-Area">
          <div id="Player">
          </div>
        <div id="Computer">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I figured the main problem is my logic with the last function. What my code does is it listens for the playerChoice using an event listener, which then gives me return value I can use to compare answers with the computer choice. This part of the code works for sure. But i can't seem to target the value attribute to update it based on one of those conditions. When I try console.log playerHealth or computerHealth to see if anything happens it still remains at 100, which is the max value I've set it as. Shouldn't my code visually lower the progress bar depending on my conditions?

https://jsfiddle.net/Jbautista1056/bLs0tyef/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems ranging from referring to the wrong variable (`Options`, instead of `options`) to not actually updating the progress bar values after evaluating the guesses.

You also have a lot of unnecessary code.

Since I'm not sure of what beats what in your game, you'll have to adjust that set of `if/else if` conditions as well as add more for the computer losing/gaining points. But, for now, if you click on `fire` or `water` repeatedly, you'll see some action. The more concise conditions and score adjustments you add, the more responsive the progress bars will be.

See the comments inline below for details:

```js
const bgURLs = {
    "Air": "https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif",
    "Fire": "https://media2.giphy.com/media/AHeTfHgVFPHgs/source.gif",
    "Water": "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/947328402825377319/20625B881E545FF98AF1A48BAC52D4CBD207101B/"
};

// Don't set variables equal to DOM element properties directly
// because every time you want a different property, you have to
// query the DOM for the same element over and over. Just get a
// reference to the element and when you want a property, just
// get it from that element reference.
let player = document.getElementById("Player");
let computer = document.getElementById("Computer");
let playerProg = document.getElementById("player-health");
let computerProg = document.getElementById("computer-health");
let options = document.getElementById("Options");

// These need to be declared so they can be accessed throughout
// the game, but their values won't be known until an event happens
let playerChoice = null;
let computerChoice = null;
let playerHealth = 100;
let computerHealth = 100;

function getComputerChoice() {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(bgURLs).length);
  computerChoice = Object.keys(bgURLs)[random];
  return computerChoice;
}

// You had Options here, but your variable is options
options.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
  if (e.target.classList.contains("element")) { 
    // Set the player choices
    playerChoice = e.target.id;
    player.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgURLs[playerChoice] + ')';   
    computer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgURLs[getComputerChoice()] + ')';
    
    // Test the results:
    console.clear();
    console.log(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    
    // Now update the progress bars
    compareChoices();
  }
})

function compareChoices() {
  // Use && for logical AND short-circuiting
  // Ensure that scores don't go below 0 or above 100
  // Not sure what beats what so you'll have to adjust as needed.
  if (playerChoice === "Air" && computerChoice === "Fire") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : computerHealth;
  } else if (playerChoice === "Air" && computerChoice === "Water") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : computerHealth;     
  } else if (playerChoice === "Fire" && computerChoice === "Air") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : computerHealth;     
  } else if (playerChoice === "Fire" && computerChoice === "Water") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : computerHealth;      
  } else if (playerChoice === "Water" && computerChoice === "Air") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : computerHealth;      
  } else if (playerChoice === "Water" && computerChoice === "Fire") {
     playerHealth = (playerHealth += 25) > 100 ? 100 : playerHealth;
     computerHealth = (computerHealth -= 25) < 0 ? 0 : computerHealth;       
  }
 
  // You must update the progress bars from within the function
  // that changes their values.
  playerProg.value = playerHealth;
  computerProg.value = computerHealth;
}
```

```css
#Player, #Computer { 
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.element { cursor:pointer; display:inline; font-weight:bold; }

#Play-Area { clear:both; }
#Play-Area div { display:inline-block; }

#PlayerBar, #ComputerBar {
  margin:10px 10px; float:left;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose Your Element</p>

<div id="Options" >
  <div id="Air" class="element">Air</div>
  <div id="Fire" class="element">Fire</div>
  <div id="Water" class="element">Water</div>
</div>

<div id="PlayerBar">
  <div>Player Health</div>
  <progress id="player-health" value="100" max="100"></progress>
</div>

<div id="ComputerBar">
 <div>Computer Health</div>
 <progress id="computer-health" value="100" max="100"></progress>
</div>

<div id="Play-Area">
  <div id="Player"></div>
  <div id="Computer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going into depth about this. It's really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I did this a while ago, and shows different bars, basically what you are aiming for.
The calculations are there and also the bars are shown in different colors(inline CSS).

```js
function myMax() {

document.myform.num1.value=document.myform.number1.value;
document.myform.num3.value=document.myform.number2.value;
document.myform.num2.value=document.myform.number3.value;
document.myform.num4.value=document.myform.number4.value;

document.myform.max1y2.value=Math.max(document.myform.num1.value,document.myform.num2.value);
document.myform.max3y4.value=Math.max(document.myform.num3.value,document.myform.num4.value);

document.myform.maxAll.value=Math.max(document.myform.max1y2.value,document.myform.max3y4.value);

if(isNaN(document.myform.maxAll.value)){alert("Error in page, Probably Not A Number in a Value");return false;}
else

document.myform.pct1.value=Math.floor((document.myform.num1.value / document.myform.maxAll.value) * 100);
document.getElementById("bar1").style.width = document.myform.pct1.value+'%';
document.myform.pct2.value=Math.floor((document.myform.num2.value / document.myform.maxAll.value) * 100);
document.getElementById("bar2").style.width = document.myform.pct2.value+'%';

document.myform.pct3.value=Math.floor((document.myform.num3.value / document.myform.maxAll.value) * 100);
document.getElementById("bar3").style.width = document.myform.pct3.value+'%';
document.myform.pct4.value=Math.floor((document.myform.num4.value / document.myform.maxAll.value) * 100);
document.getElementById("bar4").style.width = document.myform.pct4.value+'%';

}



function checkIt(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 46 || charCode > 46 )) {//set for 46 dot. For dash = (charCode < 45 || charCode > 45 ) 
        status = "This field accepts numbers only."
        return false
    }
    status = ""
 
   return true
}
```

```html
<hr style="position:relative;top: -28px;border: 4px solid black;">

 <h3 style="width: 50%;background-color:navy;color:white;position:relative;top: -28px;">&nbsp;VALUES:
</h3>
<b style="position:relative;top: -38px;">Please fill only 3 Values out of 4:
</b>

<form align="left" name="myform" style="position:relative;top: -40px;"><br>

<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="34%">
 <tbody>
 <tr><th>[Column A]</th>
 </tr><tr>

    <!-- Column 1 Row 1 -->
    <td>
<div align="left"><font color="olive"> Value 1 <input name="number1" size="8" maxlength="" tabindex="1" onblur="myMax()" onkeypress="return checkIt(event)" autofocus="" type="tel"><input name="unitA" size="4" value="Unit A" readonly="readonly" type="text"></font></div><font color="olive">
    </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Column 1 Row 2  -->
    <td>        
<div align="left"><font color="orange">Value 3 </font><input name="number2" size="8" maxlength="" tabindex="3" onblur="myMax()" onkeypress="return checkIt(event)" type="tel"><input name="unitA" size="4" value="Unit A" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<input title="Clear Value 3" type="button" onclick="document.myform.number2.value='';document.myform.number2.focus();return false" value="X">
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" height="67" width="5%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <div style="font-family:arial;font-weight:bold" align="center"><br><br> =</div>
   </td>
  </tr>   
</tbody></table>



<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="34%">
  <tbody>
     <tr><th>[Column B]</th>  
  </tr><tr>
    <!-- Column 2 Row 1 -->
    <td>
   <div align="left"><font color="green">Value 2 </font> <input name="number3" size="8" maxlength="" tabindex="2" onblur="myMax()" onkeypress="return checkIt(event)" type="tel">
 <input name="unitB" size="4" value="Unit B" readonly="readonly" type="text">     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Column 2 Row 2 -->
    <td>
        
<div align="left"><font color="red">Value 4 <input name="number4" size="8" maxlength="" tabindex="4" onblur="num4.value=this.value;myMax()" onkeypress="return checkIt(event)" type="tel">
<input name="unitB" size="4" value="Unit B" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<input title="Clear Value 4" type="button" onclick="document.myform.number4.value='';document.myform.number4.focus();return false" value="X">
</font></div><font color="red">
</font></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>




<font color=olive>Value 1 </font><input name=num1 maxlength="" type="text" readonly><input name=pct1 maxlength="" size="4" type="text" readonly>%
<div style="position:relative;top: -4px; text-align:none;">

<div style="height: 20px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd;">
<div id=bar1 style="height: 20px; background-color: olive; width: 0%;" align="left" ></div>
</div>
<font color=green>Value 2 </font><input name=num2 maxlength="" type="text" readonly><input name=pct2 maxlength="" size="4" type="text" readonly>%
<div style="position:relative;top: -4px; height: 20px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd;">
<div id=bar2 style="height: 20px; background-color: green; width: 0%;" align="left" ></div>


<!-- Ruler -->
<div style="z-index:50;position: relative;height: 18px; border-top: 2px dashed silver; width: 100%;">0%</div><center style="z-index:20;position:relative;top: -20px;"> 50% </center>
<div style="z-index:20;position:relative;top: -38px; text-align:right;">100%</div>
<!-- /Ruler -->

</div></div>

<div style="position:relative;top: 8px; text-align:none;">
Max from 1&2 = <input name=max1y2 maxlength="" type="text" readonly>
</div>


<br><br>

<font color=orange>Value 3 </font><input name=num3 maxlength="" type="text" readonly><input name=pct3 maxlength="" size="4" type="text" readonly>%
<div style="position:relative;top: -4px; text-align:none;">

<div style="height: 20px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd;">
<div id=bar3 style="height: 20px; background-color: orange; width: 0%;" align="left" ></div>
</div>
<font color=red>Value 4 </font><input name=num4 maxlength="" type="text" readonly><input name=pct4 maxlength="" size="4" type="text" readonly>%
<div style="position:relative;top: -4px; height: 20px; width: 100%; background-color: #ddd;">
<div id=bar4 style="height: 20px; background-color: red; width: 0%;" align="left" ></div>
<!-- Ruler -->
<div style="z-index:50;position: relative;height: 18px; border-top: 2px dashed silver; width: 100%;">0%</div><center style="z-index:20;position:relative;top: -20px;"> 50% </center>
<div style="z-index:20;position:relative;top: -38px; text-align:right;">100%</div>
<!-- /Ruler -->

</div></div>

<div style="position:relative;top: 8px; text-align:none;">
Max from 3&4 = <input name=max3y4 maxlength="" type="text" readonly>
<br>
Max from All <input name=maxAll maxlength="" type="text" readonly></div>
<br>
```

I hope this helps,

Ramon

Comment: Don't forget to fill the Snippet Values, later to scroll and see the results.

You can probably modify that to fit your needs.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question being asked. It uses a `form` element, which it shouldn't since there is no data being submitted anywhere. It uses `input` elements, which the OP doesn't use. It uses the depricated `font` tag (seriously?) And, it uses a `table` for layout, which is a HUGE "no no", while skipping over the OPs actual use case.

Comment: aww thanks for trying but yeah he's right im not using a table or any input elements anywhere in my code.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism.
I am an old guy that was sharing some old code.

My apologies for giving deprecated(not depricated) code.

This will discourage me from attempting to help the next time.